# Why does iOS prevent binding to UDP port 6785 (IN_ADDRANY)?

Tags: ios, network-programming

I am working on an app that uses UDP port 6785 to discover network connected dataloggers.  My app attempts to call bind() as follows:

```
  int socket_handle;
  int error = 0;

  socket_handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if(socket_handle < 0)
     error = errno;
  if(error == 0)
  {
     struct sockaddr_in addr;
     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
     addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     addr.sin_port = htons(6785);
     addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     error = bind(socket_handle, (struct sockaddr const *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
  }
```

The error returned from bind() is error 49 (can't assign requested address).  Is this happening because of a conflict with some internal device service or is it being blocked by the OS for some unknown reason?

It turns out that the failure does not occur if I have VPN turned off.  I had to enable VPN in order to access our local network from wifi.

Comment: So does this work if you change the port to something else?

Comment: Do you have Splashtop Remote running on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Try this before calling bind(). This solves the problem if the port is being blocked by a TIME_WAIT

```
int optval = 1;
setsockopt(socket_handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));
```